# Parameters in TI-BASIC

Tags: parameters, code-formatting, ti-basic

I have written a program that simplifies a radical, but it's kind of ugly and I am interested in "prettying" up the interface:

```
prgmSIMPRAD
IN?
R=?48
OUT:
                        4
IN:
                        3
                     DONE
```

Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
prgmSIMPRAD(48)
       4(radical symbol)3
```

After a quick google I figured out how to beautify the answer, but I'm still curious if it is possible to put a parameter in the call to the program.

Comment: And yes, I checked the documentation. Couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, this is not possible with any actual features of how the interpreter executes the program (no system variable for arguments or syntax for it as a command, but I could be wrong). You can however do something like this:

```
48:prgmSIMPRAD
```

This will pass 48 directly into the `Ans` system variable, and then execute the program (`:` is just a new line pretty much). Obviously many other things will set stuff to the Ans variable, so you'll want to store it right off the bat like:

```
Ans->A
//code here
```

Comment: I was about to answer this, luckily I scrolled up and saw it was already said.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the text formatting question:
http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/forum/t-601799/radical-simplifying

```
Input "√(",A
iPart(√(A                ;This is where we start testing for factors of A
While fPart(A/Ans²       ;repeat so long as Ans² does not perfectly divide A
Ans-1                    ;Since the previous number was not a square factor, go to the next
End
Text(0,0,Ans,"√(",A/Ans²,")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do just that by using the beauty that is the `Output(` command.

You can go about this by counting digits of both numbers (see documentation for `log(`), using `If` commands to check if either number is zero, and of course, displaying `√(` as string.